# Add instructions to featured image

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

How do you add instructions to the featured image field (see attached screenshot) - something like: "recommended dimensions - H980px by W450px"..?

[image: screenshot of featured image without instructions]

Comment: Looks like this is possible but requires a bit of cide, are you able to edit your functions.php or setup a new plugin to do this?

Comment: @mozboz yes, I can edit my functions.php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress has a hook for that.  Here is a sample code:

```
function featured_image_dimensions( $content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id ){
    $help_text = '<p>' . __( 'recommended dimensions - H980px by W450px', 'my_domain' ) . '</p>';
    return $help_text . $content;
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'featured_image_dimensions', 10, 3 );
```

Add this code to your functions.php and you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you so much... this helped.